# Create a fork from a locally edited repo? I cloned and edited, too late to fork it to capture my changes?

Tags: git, github

So I cloned a sample solution and started tinkering to suit my needs.  Learn, tinker, learn, success!

All is well...

But now I would like to capture my edits and manage them as a fork in my own system.

Is it too late?  I am sure I can get a git command to show me my edits from the original repo.  How can I now save them (with history) to a new repo in my system?

Pretty much a git noob.

Answer (score 2):

In some way, your local clone is already a fork: the changes you made on your machine are present only there and not upstream.

If you mean to create a repository *on github* which is listed as a fork of the original repository, it is also perfectly doable:

1. through Github GUI, create a fork of the source repository
2. on your local repository, add the url to your clone as a remote url:

```
# option 1: create a remote with a new name
git remote add myfork git@github.com/myaccount/reponame

# option 2: update 'origin'
git remote set-url origin git@github.com/myaccount/reponame
```

3. push your changes to that remote

```
# depending on what you chose at step 2.:
git push myfork ...
git push origin ...
```

All the commits on your disk are exact copies of the original commits (same content, same sha), the histories will combine just fine.

---

FWIW, I like to have :

- `origin` pointing to my writeable clone,
- a remote named `upstream` pointing to the source repo,
- `origin` showing up as the first remote, so it is the default choice

From your setup, that would be the following two commands:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com/myaccount/reponame
git remote add upstream https://github.com/sourceaccount/reponame
```

You can now run `git push` and `git fetch / git pull` (with no extra arguments) to interact with your fork, and `git fetch upstream` to update branches from the upstream repository.